# Can't figure out how to change the background of a html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out how to change the backgound of a html. It's not just a picture that you can replace. Can someone point me the part where I should look after? All I got is some css files and the images folder. I've been searching for some time and I got a few hours to present this site to someone and I don't like the blue background on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">

  <title>Lumea Criptomonedelor</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fonts/themify/style.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/animate/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/flipclock/flipclock.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/vendors/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/demo.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/template-3d-animation.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body class=" 1-column undefined  page-animated svg-wrapper" data-menu-open="hover" data-menu="">
  <header class="page-header">
    <nav class="main-menu static-top navbar-dark navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top mb-1 " arial-label="next-slide>
            <div class=" container ">
                <a class="navbar-brand animated " href="#head-area "><img src="assets/images-3d-animation/logo.png " alt="Crypto Logo "/><span class="brand-text ">Lumea Criptomonedelor   </span></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#navbarCollapse " aria-controls="navbarCollapse " aria-expanded="false " aria-label="Toggle navigation ">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarCollapse ">
                    <div id="navigation " class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-1 ">
                            <li class="nav-item animated " >
                                <a class="nav-link " href="index.html#about ">Home</a>
                            </li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item animated " >
                                <a class="nav-link " href="bitcoin.html ">Bitcoin</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item animated ">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="ethereum.html ">Ethereum</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item animated " >
                                <a class="nav-link " href="ripple.html ">Ripple</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <span id="slide-line "></span>
                        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0 ">
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-gradient-purple btn-glow my-2 my-sm-0 animated " href="despre.html ">Despre</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="content-wrapper ">
        <div class="content-body ">
            <main>

                <section class="head-area " id="head-area ">
                    <div id="particles-js "></div>
                    
                </section>

                <section class="about section-padding " id="about ">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="heading text-center ">
                            <div class="animated " >
                                <h6 class="sub-title ">Introducere</h6>
                                <h2 class="title ">Ce sunt criptomonedele?</h2>
                            </div>
                            <p class="content-desc animated " >Criptomonedă sau criptovalută este un tip de monedă digitală, virtuală, o monedă surogat, nebancară, folosită ca mijloc de plată. Denumirea de criptomonedă indică faptul că acest mijloc de plată utilizează criptografia 
                                <br class="d-none d-xl-block ">și este descentralizat pentru a controla tranzacțiile și preveni dubla cheltuială, o problemă curentă pentru valutele digitale.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-area ">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 ">
                                    <h4 class="title animated " >Monedele virtuale sunt folosite <br class="d-none d-xl-block "> pentru a face plăți electronice de orice valoare.</h4>
                                    <h6 class="pt-4 pb-2 animated " >Pe scurt, moneda electronică este varianta electronică a bancnotelor și monedelor, care se poate stoca pe un dispozitiv de plată electronic (e-money).</h6>
                                    <p class="animated " >Deseori se face greșeala ca moneda virtuală (criptomoneda) să fie considerată o monedă electronică. Conform legii, aceasta nu este o monedă electronică. Astfel, în România, art. 4 lit. f din Legea 127/2011 privind activitatea de emitere de monedă electronică, definește moneda electronică ca fiind „o valoare monetară stocată electronic, inclusiv magnetic, reprezentând o creanță asupra emitentului, emisă la primirea fondurilor în scopul efectuării de operațiuni de plată și care este acceptată de o persoană, alta decât emitentul de monedă electronică”.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section id="problem-solution " class="problem-solution section-pro section-padding ">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="heading text-center ">
                            <div class="animated " >
                                <h6 class="sub-title ">AVANTAJE</h6>
                                <h2 class="title ">Avantaje &amp; <strong>Dezavantaje</strong></h2>
                            </div>
                            <p class="content-desc animated " >More than $40 million in assets were placed under restraint pending forfeiture, and more than 30
                                <br class="d-none d-xl-block ">Liberty Reserve exchanger domain names were seized.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="problems ">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 ">
                                    <div class="heading mb-4 ">
                                        <h4 class="title animated " >Avantaje</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul style="color: #FFF; ">
                                        <li class="animated " >- Este un sistem descentralizat, nu există o autoritate centrală, cum ar fi o bancă centrală</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Datele personale despre utilizatori sunt ascunse</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Se poate crea o copie de rezervă criptată a monedei virtuale</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Plata se poate face fără ca datele personale să fie asociate cu tranzacția</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Utilizatorii au în permanență controlul tranzacțiilor</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Transfer foarte rapid oriunde în lume</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Nu există limită de sumă pentru transferuri</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Comisioane variabile</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center ">
                                    <img src="assets/images-3d-animation/problems-graphic.png " class="problems-img animated "  alt="problems-graphic ">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="solutions mt-5 ">
                            <div class="row ">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 text-center ">
                                    <img src="assets/images-3d-animation/solutions-graphic.png " class="solutions-img animated "  alt="problems-graphic ">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 move-first ">
                                    <div class="heading mb-4 ">
                                        <h4 class="title animated ">Dezavantaje</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul style="color: #FFF; ">
                                        <li class="animated " >- Utilizare redusă</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Volatilitatea datorită faptului că moneda este în cantitate limitată, iar valoarea ei este dată de cerere și ofertă</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Ireversibilitatea tranzacțiilor, anularea fiind imposibilă</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Interdicția utilizării anumitor criptomonede în unele țări</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Distribuția neuniformă a criptomonedei între primii utilizatori și cei actuali</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Necesită un înalt nivel de securitate</li>
                                        <li class="animated " >- Nu toți comercianții acceptă cripomoneda ca metodă de plată.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <section id="faq " class="faq section-padding ">
                    <div class="container ">
                        <div class="heading text-center ">
                            <div class="animated " >
                                <h6 class="sub-title ">Întrebări</h6>
                                <h2 class="title ">Întrebări frecvente</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col ">
                                <nav>
                                    <div class="nav nav-pills nav-underline mb-5 animated "  id="myTab " role="tablist ">
                                    </div>
                                </nav>
                                <div class="tab-content " id="myTabContent ">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active " id="caracteristici " role="tabpanel " aria-labelledby="caracteristici-tab ">
                                        <div id="general-accordion " class="collapse-icon accordion-icon-rotate ">
                                            <div class="card animated " >
                                                <div class="card-header " id="headingOne ">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                                                        <a class="btn-link " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#collapseOne " aria-expanded="true " aria-controls="collapseOne ">
                                                            <span class="icon "></span>
                                                            Ce este mineritul ?
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseOne " class="collapse show " aria-labelledby="headingOne " data-parent="#general-accordion ">
                                                    <div class="card-body ">
                                                        Criptomoneda poate fi cumpărată, dar și creată. Procesul de creare a monedei se numește „minerit”. Participanții în rețea sunt cunoscuți sub numele de mineri (engleză: miners). Aceștia verifică, datează tranzacțiile și le partajează într-o bază de date publică, numită blockchain (lanț de blocuri). Există noduri specializate care validează tranzacțiile și blocurile și le conectează între punctele tranzacției. 

                                                        Operațiunea de minerit este deosebit de complexă și este foarte dificil de realizat pe cont propriu, de un singur utilizator. Astfel, s-au dezvoltat grupuri de mineri, numite mining pools. Un grup de mineri combină puterea lor de procesare pentru rezolvarea algoritmilor producători de criptomonede. 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card animated " >
                                                <div class="card-header " id="headingTwo ">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                                                        <a class="btn-link collapsed " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#collapseTwo " aria-expanded="false " aria-controls="collapseTwo ">
                                                            <span class="icon "></span>
                                                            Ce folosim din punct de vedere hardware ?
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseTwo " class="collapse " aria-labelledby="headingTwo " data-parent="#general-accordion ">
                                                    <div class="card-body ">
                                                        Mineritul de criptomonedă presupune folosirea puterii de calcul a sistemelor PC pentru operațiunea de mining. Sunt dezvoltate mai multe sisteme dedicate pentru mineritul de criptomonede. Aceste dispozitive se numesc ASIC (Application Specific Integrated Circuit) și reprezintă niște circuite integrate cu cipuri programate în mod permanent și cu o aplicație integrată în cipurile respective. Două companii populare ce oferă instalații de minerit tip ASIC sunt Avalon Asics și Butterfly Labs.
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card animated " >
                                                <div class="card-header " id="headingThree ">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-0 ">
                                                        <a class="btn-link collapsed " data-toggle="collapse " data-target="#collapseThree " aria-expanded="false " aria-controls="collapseThree ">
                                                            <span class="icon "></span>
                                                            Ce folosim din punct de vedere software ?
                                                        </a>
                                                    </h5>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseThree " class="collapse " aria-labelledby="headingThree " data-parent="#general-accordion ">
                                                    <div class="card-body ">
                                                        În timp ce procesul de minerit în sine este făcut de hardware, este nevoie de software special pentru a conecta minerii la blockchain și mining pool. Software-ul poate să ruleze pe aproape orice sistem de operare, cum ar fi Mac OS X, Windows, Linux. Programul transmite informații și rezultate către miner, dar și monitorizează statisticile generale cum ar fi temperatura, hashrate-ul, viteza ventilatorului, viteza medie a minerului etc.
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                
                <div class="modal ico-modal fade " id="ico-modal " tabindex="-1 " role="dialog " aria-hidden="true ">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered " role="document ">
                        <div class="modal-content ">
                            <button type="button " class="close " data-dismiss="modal " aria-label="Close ">
                                <span aria-hidden="true ">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="modal-body p-0 ">
                                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 ">
                                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item " id="video "></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </main>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer static-bottom footer-dark footer-custom-class " data-midnight="white ">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="footer-wrapper ">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="about ">
                            <div class="title animated " >
                                <span class="logo-text ">Lumea Criptomonedelor</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="about-text animated " >
                                <p class="grey-accent2 ">Criptomonedă sau criptovalută este un tip de monedă digitală, virtuală, o monedă surogat, nebancară, folosită ca mijloc de plată.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="col-md-4 ">
                            <div class="links ">
                                <h5 class="title "  >Legături utile</h5>
                                <ul class="useful-links ">
                                    <li class=" "  ><a href="bitcoin.html ">Bitcoin</a></li>
                                    <li class=" "  ><a href="ethereum.html ">Ethereum</a></li>
                                    <li class=" "  ><a href="ripple.html ">Ripple</a></li>
                                    <li class=" "  ><a href="despre.html ">Despre</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 ">
                        <div class="feed ">
                            <h5 class="title animated " >Info</h5>
                            <div class="tweets ">
                                <span class="animated " > Denumirea de criptomonedă indică faptul că acest mijloc de plată utilizează criptografia și este descentralizat pentru a controla tranzacțiile și preveni dubla cheltuială, o problemă curentă pentru valutele digitale.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="copy-right mx-auto text-center ">
                    <span class="copyright ">Proiect pentru susținerea examenului de Atestat la Informatică</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="assets/vendors/vendors.min.js "></script>

    <script src="assets/vendors/flipclock/flipclock.min.js "></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/swiper/js/swiper.min.js "></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/particles.min.js "></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/waypoints/jquery.waypoints.min.js "></script>

    <script src="assets/js/theme.min.js "></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts/demo.min.js "></script>

    <script src="assets/js/scripts/particles-type1.min.js "></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the background color of the entire html page, you can go to the style.css file and put right at the top:

```
body {
  background-color: {color you want to use}
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work still that ugly color.

Comment: You probably have a class in your style.css file with a background-color set to the ugly color! Since I can't see the style.css file, I can't really help... but there's a change it's there.

Comment: I ctrl+f and search for the background-color and I don't find anything. Can I send all the files that I have? I'm just stressed that I can't find the thing I need

Comment: Add me on Discord KobaCK#3502 and send me the .zip file of everything, and I'll see what I can do